# Generating a single definition file from a external module typescript project

Tags: module, compilation, typescript, definitions

Having a multi file typescript project, using external modules.

If I compile with

```
tsc -d init.ts -m "commonjs"
```

Then all the files of the project get their own .d.ts file.
But I would like to generate one single .d.ts file for the whole project.
What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle seems to contain an answer or initial code base for your own solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I would like to generate one single .d.ts file for the whole project. What's the best way to go about this?

At the moment it is handled in a hacky way by : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-dts-bundle

More : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1236

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a single d.ts and a .ts and .js bundle using the npm package [TsProject](http://www.npmjs.com/package/tsproject).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "**npm-dts**" package. I think it does exactly what you need.

Also, there is a plugin for WebPack called "**npm-dts-webpack-plugin**".